# How to make Windows force sleep, ignoring everything preventing sleep?

Tags: windows-11, sleep

I'm aware of **powercfg/requestsoverride** but is there a way to make it ignore **everything**?

I have multiple, USB, audio devices etc. and it's difficult to find and add them all.

I want my PC to go to sleep after 1 hour of not using my mouse, regardless of what's currently happening. I never use the PC to watch videos or anything, so if my mouse has not been moved, I'm not in front of the PC and want it to sleep.